# Learning CI/CD - need Demo Application

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, demo

I'm learning CI/CD and I'd like to work with some real code as part of my builds and deploys. I don't want to use any of the code from work as a this is being done on my time.

Does anyone have recommendations of a multi-tiered (linux based) application that I can use to master CI/CD?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example, i would suggest taking an open source application (any or the gnu tools, or your own perl/ruby/python code) and create a local gitlab + Jenkins solution

Add automated tests in your code that can be run as part of the Jenkins CI (using a hook, run tests during build time)

Comment: That's what my approach was going to be.  the challenge is finding a good example application to use.

Comment: how about https://github.com/docker/docker, you can then extend the functionality of Jenkins (after you have the CI work stuff done), to run the build/test in a docker instance :D. It shoud not matter once you pick an application that has some automated tests. Even using binutils or zip